# How can I search the following line using Selenium with Python? Im trying to find and click this specific button that represents the size of a shoe

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

```
<button type="button" class="size-grid-dropdown size-grid-button" data-qa="size-dropdown">M 12 / W 13.5</button>
```

Below is the Python snippet of the script I have so far.

```
import time
import selenium import webdriver

url = 'some url'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_link_text('M 12 / 13.5').click()
```

The output I'm is the following:

```
Unable to locate element: M 12 / W 13.5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could there be an `<iframe>` on the page?

Comment: Could you show us your url?

Answer (score 0):

Use the xpath as shown below: double quotes with black slash

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@text,\"M 12 / 13.5\")]"));
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but im still getting the same output

Comment: //button[contains(@text,'M 12')] try this instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
list_items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")

search_ = "M 12 / 13.5"
for item in list_items:
    if search_ in item.text:
        item.click()
```